# Chrome breakpoints jump to different lines

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gruntjs, source-maps, grunt-browserify

I'm running Chrome 48.0 and lately when I try to place breakpoints in the developer console, sometimes they will refuse to be placed at certain lines and instead jump to another line instead.  Almost like when you try to place a breakpoint on a line that doesn't make sense (such as a bracket by itself), but these are just regular lines.  If I make a change to my code, the lines that will refuse to work might change, and lines that worked before might stop working.

I'm assuming this is something to do with source mapping, but I'm confused as to why some lines work correctly, and the line right after it will not.

I'm using grunt-browserify with babelify and babel-preset-react, babel-preset-es2015, and babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread:

```
    options: {
      transform: [['babelify', {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
        plugins: ['syntax-object-rest-spread'],
      }]],
      browserifyOptions: {
        extensions: ['.jsx'],
        paths: [absPath + '/js', absPath],
        debug: true // Adds source maps to output
      },
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: typically issue with lines mapping means some issue with generating source-map itself; so it's quite small chance to handle it by yourselves; probably you just can try another processing tool